# Algorithms for factorizing a 30 decimal digit number

Tags: cryptography, prime-factoring, factorization

My professor has given me an RSA factoring problem has assignment. The given modulus is 30 decimal digits long. I have been searching a lot about factoring algorithms. But it has been quite a headache to choose one for my given requirements. Which all algorithms give better performance for 30 decimal digit numbers?

Note: So far I have read about Brute force approach and Quadratic Sieve. The latter is complex and the former time consuming.

Comment: you need the general number field sieve

Comment: @Woodstock oh lord! isn't that too complicated?

Comment: ummm, yup but you don't have to implement it, just use it! Does that help? If so I will write up an answer

Comment: @Woodstock The professor needs screenshots of implementation attached in the report. So...

Comment: Is he expecting you to literally implement the algorithm? Or just show you understand the implementation? If the latter you can just use something like this: http://gilchrist.ca/jeff/factoring/nfs_beginners_guide.html

Comment: @Woodstock to make it clear. This is how it has been given in the assignment's Question 8: "briefly - in one paragraph - describe the design of your code. Attach the implementation of factoring algorithm". Please do tell me if I'm understanding it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another method called [Pollard's Rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), which is not as fast as the GNFS but is capable of factoring 30-digit numbers in minutes rather than hours.

The algorithm is very simple. It stops when it finds any factor, so you'll need to call it recursively to obtain a complete factorisation. Here's a basic implementation in Python:

```py
def rho(n):
    def gcd(a, b):
        while b > 0:
            a, b = b, a%b
        return a
    g = lambda z: (z**2 + 1) % n
    x, y, d = 2, 2, 1
    while d == 1:
        x = g(x)
        y = g(g(y))
        d = gcd(abs(x-y), n)
    if d == 0:
        print("Can't factor this, sorry.")
        print("Try a different polynomial for g(), maybe?")
    else:
        print("%d = %d * %d" % (n, d, n // d))

rho(441693463910910230162813378557) # = 763728550191017 * 578338290221621
```

Or you could just use an existing software library. I can't see much point in reinventing this particular wheel.

Comment: An update i have spend more than a week trying to implement quadratic sieve. But, oh boy! I should have never overlooked pollard-rho. Thank you to all folks that helped me.